# libpepflashplayer.so: 0x15B4E is not a valid resource ID

Tags: webcam, flash

I am working with flash player to show webcam. Sometime I get this error in chrome console.

"libpepflashplayer.so: 0x15B4E is not a valid resource ID."

What could be the reason?

Comment: I compiled the movie as newer version (11 instead of 10) and the error has been fixed.